# Imprimir una etiqueta <i> por cada ng-repeat de un Json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ng-repeat

Teniendo las siguiente estrucura, ¿COMO HAGO para imprimir la cantidad de estrelas que tiene cada auto? osea. SI en el json dice "stars":"3" tendria que imprimir 3 etiquetas

El resultado esperado es que se impriman 3  ; El primero con 3  dentro. El segundo  con 4  dentro y el ultimo con 2  dentro.

Por Favor ayuda!

** app.js | data.json | HTML **

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appController", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('/data.json').success(function(data) {

    $scope.autos = data.autos;

  });
});
```

```css
{
  "Autos" : [
    {
      "name" : "BMW",
      "stars" : "3",
    },
    {
      "name" : "Ferrari",
      "stars" : "4",
    },
    {
      "name" : "Ford",
      "stars" : "2",
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="appController">
  <div>
    <i ng-repeat="star in autos" class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero una funcion para almacenar en un arreglo las estrellas de acuerdo al `Json`

```js
var varJson={
  "Autos" : [
    {
      "name" : "BMW",
      "stars" : "3",
    },
    {
      "name" : "Ferrari",
      "stars" : "4",
    },
    {
      "name" : "Ford",
      "stars" : "2",
    }
  ]
};
varJson.Autos.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
var estrellas="";
  for(var x=0;x<currentValue.stars;x++){
   estrellas+="*";
  }
  console.log(estrellas);
})
```

utilizando la función de arriba, almacenamos las estrellas en `contenedorDeEstrellas`, y devolvemos al $scope `$scope.contenedorDeEstrellas=contenedorDeEstrellas;`

```js
function appController($scope) {
  
  var varJson={
  "Autos" : [
    {
      "name" : "BMW",
      "stars" : "3",
    },
    {
      "name" : "Ferrari",
      "stars" : "4",
    },
    {
      "name" : "Ford",
      "stars" : "2",
    }
  ]
};
var contenedorDeEstrellas=[];
varJson.Autos.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
var estrellas="";
  for(var x=0;x<currentValue.stars;x++){
   estrellas+="*";
  }
  contenedorDeEstrellas.push({star:estrellas});
})

$scope.contenedorDeEstrellas=contenedorDeEstrellas;


};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="estrellas in contenedorDeEstrellas" class="fa fa-star">{{estrellas.star}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***ahora si quieres agregar la etiqueta `li` de acuerdo a las estrellas (3,4,2)
el siguiente codigo te puede ayudar:***

```js
    function appController($scope) {
      
      var varJson={
      "Autos" : [
        {
          "name" : "BMW",
          "stars" : "3",
        },
        {
          "name" : "Ferrari",
          "stars" : "4",
        },
        {
          "name" : "Ford",
          "stars" : "2",
        }
      ]
    };
    var contenedorDeEstrellas=[];
    varJson.Autos.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
    var estrellas="";
      for(var x=0;x<currentValue.stars;x++){
       estrellas+="*";
       contenedorDeEstrellas.push({star:estrellas});
      }
      
    })

    $scope.contenedorDeEstrellas=contenedorDeEstrellas;


    };
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="appController">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="estrellas in contenedorDeEstrellas" class="fa fa-star">{{estrellas.star}}
<li ></li>

</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esto al estilo `angular` tienes que poner el valor que quieres mostrar en el código html. La linea quedaría así:

`<i ng-repeat="star in autos" class="fa fa-star">{{star.name}}</i>`

Te dejo un ejemplo de como funcionaría (adaptando un poco lo que tu tienes:

```js
function appController($scope) {

  $scope.autos = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "stars": "3",
  }, {
    "name": "Ferrari",
    "stars": "4",
  }, {
    "name": "Ford",
    "stars": "2",
  }];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="star in autos" class="fa fa-star">{{star.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea un ng repeat dentro de un ng repeat, como un for anidado

```html
  
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
      <ul ng-repeat="auto in autos" class="fa fa-star">auto.name</ul>
        <i ng-repeat="star in auto.star" class="fa fa-star">Estrella</i>
          
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿COMO HAGO para imprimir la cantidad de estrellas que tiene cada auto?

Una solución seria crear un `array` de longitud igual a la cantidad de estrellas.

- Usando `angular.forEach`, el constructor `Array(length)` y `ng-repeat track by`:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appController", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('/data.json')
  .then(function(data) {
    var autos = data.Autos;
    // Por cada auto
    angular.forEach(autos, function(auto) {
      // Creamos un arreglo de logintud igual a la cantidad de estrellas
      auto.arrayStars = Array(parseInt(auto.stars, 10));
    });
    //
    $scope.autos = autos;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="appController">
    <li ng-repeat="auto in autos">
      {{auto.name}}
      <i ng-repeat="n in auto.arrayStars track by $index" class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/h12mmb1t/1/)

- Usando `ng-repeat` combiando con un `filter` custom:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

// Custom filter
app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total, 10);
    for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };
});

app.controller("appController", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('/data.json')
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.autos = data.Autos;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="appController">
    <li ng-repeat="auto in autos">
      {{auto.name}}
      <i ng-repeat="n in [] | range:auto.stars" class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/h12mmb1t/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un ng-repeat anidado.

```
<div ng-repeat="auto in autos">
    <i ng-repeat="star in getArray(auto.stars)" class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

En el controlador hacer una función que te regrese un arreglo con el número de estrellas que se requiera, el contenido no importa ya que solo necesitamos que ng-repeat se ejecute el número de veces que indica el argumento *stars*:

```
getArray: function(stars) {
    return new Array(start);
}
```

El primer ng-repeat recorre el arreglo de autos, el segundo coloca en pantalla el numero de estrellas que indica la propiedad stars.

Comment: Te en cuenta que `auto.stars` es un `string`, por lo que es necesario hacer un `parseInt`. De lo contrario se crearia un `array` de longitud 1 con un solo valor.